# Unsmooth, lagging animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-xml

I have used animation on an activity in my game where user sees his score in form of stars(maximum score gets 3 stars). I have used animation on each of the stars(using **startAnimation()** method). The golden stars gets placed on the blank grey colored stars with translation, scale and alpha animation(I have used set animation).
But whenever that score activity starts the animation gets displayed with jerkiness/lag/unsmoothness.
Whats the **solution to make that animation smooth and timely**?

Following is the java code to dislplay 3 out of 3 stars

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         ............
        Myanim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_scale_left);
        Myanim2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.aplha_scale_mid);
        Myanim3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.alpha_scale_right);
          ......}

if(pattern_Score>targetScore*90/100)
            {
                mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000,100) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    starIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gray);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    starIv1.startAnimation(Myanim1);
                    starIv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "timer1 stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();
            starIv1.clearAnimation();


                mCountDownTimer1=new CountDownTimer(2000,100) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                        starIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gray);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //starIv2.clearAnimation(); 
                        starIv2.startAnimation(Myanim2);
                        starIv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    }
                };
                mCountDownTimer1.start();
                starIv2.clearAnimation();

                mCountDownTimer2=new CountDownTimer(3000,100) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
                        starIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_gray);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        //starIv3.clearAnimation(); 
                        starIv3.startAnimation(Myanim3);
                        starIv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                    }
                };
                mCountDownTimer2.start();
                starIv3.clearAnimation();....}
```

alpha_scale_left.xml(animation on left star)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%"
           android:fromXDelta="-20%" 
           android:toYDelta="0"
           android:toXDelta="0" 
           android:duration="600"/>
<scale 
        android:fromXScale="3000%"
        android:fromYScale="3000%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="900"
    />
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="600" />


</set>
```

alpha_scale_mid.xml(animation on middle star)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%"
           android:fromXDelta="-5%" 
           android:toYDelta="0"
           android:toXDelta="0" 
           android:duration="600"/>
<scale 
        android:fromXScale="3000%"
        android:fromYScale="3000%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:duration="600"
    />
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="600" />

</set>
```

alpha_scale_right.xml(animation on right star)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%"
           android:fromXDelta="5%" 
           android:toYDelta="0"
           android:toXDelta="0" 
           android:duration="600"/>
<scale 
        android:fromXScale="3000%"
        android:fromYScale="3000%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:duration="600"
    />
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="600" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

- I don't understand the meaning of `3000%` in your **xmls** try changing in the range of `~100%`

Looking at the code I can suggest you to use some threads and not load all the animations on the main thread and you should rather use `Asynctask` and based on some progress you may use `onprogressupdate` method to make changes to the UI thread.

**OR**

> Graphics and Animations are handled by the **`GPU`** or in more common
>   term the **Processor** of your device. If not rendered properly then it
>   could possibly be the result of a processor with low clock rate.

Comment: 3000% is used here to scale it from 3000% of its original size to its original size

Comment: it will be very helpful if you can kindly explain with some code

Comment: I used AsyncTask but still its lagging, I have tested it on Nexus 7 and Galaxy Tab2, seems device is not the issue.

Comment: @user2674084 If you reduce the scaling factor do you still get the same lag ? Also make sure your animation is not present inside a loop

Comment: I guess I have got your problem , just try debugging your countdowntimer and see how many times does it execute. Basically it should execute once or twice at max if not then you are really making a mistake and put it outside of countdown timer

Comment: I have removed the `CountdownTimer` and now using `startOffset` in the xml only, but it is also of no help

Comment: Also for the debugging reason i would say you should try only with one loadAnimation function